Monnify error: Cannot convert access token to JSON
I am testing an endpoint to create virtual accounts with a fintech, but I keep getting a 401 error.
I am working with nodeJs I keep getting this error while testing in postman:
  error: 'invalid_token',
  error_description: 'Cannot convert access token to JSON'

This is my code snippet:
export async function createReservedVirtualAccount(token: string, accountReference: string, accountName: string, customerEmail: string, bvn: string, currencyCode: string, contractCode: string, getAllAvailableBanks: boolean, nin: number) {
    try {
        const url = `${MONNIFY_API_URL}/api/v2/bank-transfer/reserved-accounts`;
        const response = await axios.post(
            url,
            {
                bvn,
                accountReference,
                accountName,
                customerEmail,
                currencyCode,
                contractCode,
                getAllAvailableBanks,
                nin,
                token
            },
            {
              headers: 
                {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
            }
        );
        return response.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error creating access token:', error.response?.data || error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

